# MVC3 Razor > Make Model IEnumerable, so it can be used in View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ienumerable, razor

I have this model:

```
namespace easyBooking.Models
{
    public class CardInfo
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string adress { get; set; }
        public string zipcode { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string ccsID { get; set; }
        public string birthday { get; set; }
        public string nationalitet { get; set; }
        public string cardType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

which I populate from a function and return to the controller. The problem is that I cannot hand this model to my view, since it does not implement IEnumerable... Instead I have to add information to the viewBag like this:

```
var cardInfo = FunctionLib.cardCampingPas(myArray);
                        ViewData.Add("name", cardInfo.name);
                        ViewData.Add("adress", cardInfo.adress);
                        ViewData.Add("nationalitet", cardInfo.nationalitet);
                        ViewData.Add("ccsID", cardInfo.ccsID);
                        ViewData.Add("zipcode", cardInfo.zipcode);
                        ViewData.Add("city", cardInfo.city);
                        ViewData.Add("cardType", cardInfo.cardType);
                        return View("../Reservation/New", ViewData);
```

which is kind of stupid, when I should be able to just add the cardInfo model directly to the View.

```
    var cardInfo = FunctionLib.cardCampingPas(myArray);
    return View("../Reservation/New", cardInfo);
```

So basically I just need to pass a bunch of strings to the view. How can my model CardInfo be accessed directly from my view?

**Update**

@rene - view data where I added a @model declaration. I did get some errors when I tried it last, but it must have been because I tried to `foreach` it or something.. now... just no error, and I have no idea if anything is passed to the view or how to get the data.

```
@model easyBooking.Models.CardInfo
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New";
}
<h2>Ny reservation</h2>
<p>Benyttet kort: @Model.cardType</p>
```

This now works...

Comment: The last two lines seems OK to me. Can you share your view? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass your collection directly to the view.

In the view, you'll need to declare the model type:

```
@model IEnumerable<CardInfo>
```

Comment: `@model IEnumerable<easyBooking.Models.CardInfo>`  


Think I already tried something like this, but how to get a single value from it afterwards?

@model.name
@CardInfo.name

Comment: @Kenneth: That doesn't make any sense.  How can you get a single value from an array? You probably want to use a loop.

Comment: @sLaks exactly    

` @foreach (var item in Model)  
{  
 @item.cardType  
}`  
  
where cardType works with intelliSence and looks good to go...
but ends up giving me  

`The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'easyBooking.Models.CardInfo', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[easyBooking.Models.CardInfo]'.`

Comment: @Kenneth: That means that your controller passed a single item, not an array.

Comment: @sLaks: Absolutely no clue on how to convert/cast/force/annotate that it should be an array.

So if my model was Movie, that cannot be used in a view, instead I have to make and array eg. Movies and add that Movie to it and pass the array Movies to the view?

Comment: @Kenneth: If you have an array (or collection), pass it.  If you don't, use a single item.  You have complete control over your code; you should make it do whatever makes sense.

Comment: @sLaks: At current the code controls me, since I don't know how to get the actual value from my single item when passed to the view. Which seems to make my viewbag approach sufficient, yet inefficient.

Comment: What? You can just write `@model.SomeProperty`.

Comment: What I initially thought aswell, but @model.ccsID gives me "The 'model' keyword must be followed by a type name on the same line." 
What declaration should be used in the top of my view? Still @model IEnumerable<easyBooking.Models.CardInfo> or something else?

Comment: @Kenneth: You need to write `@Model` with an `M`; sorry.  Otherwise, it thinks you're declaring a model type.

Comment: Ah, true, but that gives my a load of functions now. ToList, ToArray etc. So if I need the ccsID value I would do @Model.[what].ccsID _
All guides I've seen so far has indeed been doing foreach and do like item.cssID

Comment: @Kenneth: That's because you declared an IEnumerable.  If you declare a raw class model, you'll get properties.

Comment: @SLaks: Brilliant, seems to work now, had to Build it once again, close the view and re-open for intellisense to actually catch the parameters. What pains me the most that I already had tried this, but discarded the idea due to intellisense not showing the values.